# Using scikit-learn for single input multiple output model in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras

I am trying to use the scikit-learn in Keras to fine tune the model that has one input(images) and 2 outputs(rotational vector and translation vector). The code snippet is as below,

```
img_input =Input(shape=(img_rows, img_cols, img_channels))
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn = toy_model, verbose = 1)
loss_weights = [[1.0, 250.0], [1.0, 500.0], [1.0, 750.0]]
epochs =[10, 20]
batches = [5, 10]
param_grid = dict(loss_weight= loss_weights, epochs = epochs, 
batch_size = batches)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid=param_grid)
grid_result = grid.fit(train_imgs, [train_pose_tx, train_pose_rt])
```

I want to fine tune the "loss_weights" parameter for this model.  However, I get the following error

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples:[895, 2]
```

As I understand since this model has single input, this functionality must be supported. 
Link to Github gist : 
https://gist.github.com/sushant4788/1f84cd2781f96fb752ee1f16a56d1bcb

Comment: Whats the shape of each of `train_imgs`, `train_pose_rt`, `train_pose_tx`, `test_imgs`, `test_pose_rt`, `test_pose_tx`?

Comment: The shapes are (3833, 224, 224, 3), (3833, 4), (3833, 3), (1158, 224, 224, 3), (1158, 4) and (1158, 3) respectively. I have updated the Gist for a complete error message. Thank you.